# How to align a scatter trace on grouped bar chart with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm quite new to r plotly and have created a bar chart showing income sources grouped by year for disabled people. Now I'm trying to add a scatter trace to show the comparison with markers for non-disabled people, but the markers aren't aligning properly, they align centrally on the x-axis category rather than grouping by the year variable like the bars. From googling, I found someone else had the same issue on github, but didn't see a solution. Is there a simple way to make the markers for the scatter trace align by the year variable so they align with the bars?

I need to produce this for 7 charts in an html report, so would appreciate some help.

My data for this chart:

```
structure(list(Disability = c("Disabled", "Disabled", "Disabled"
), Year = c("2017/18", "2018/19", "2019/20"), `Wages and salaries` = c(0.32, 
0.34, 0.37), `All Pensions` = c(0.34, 0.32, 0.31), `All Social Security benefits` = c(0.37, 
0.27, 0.23), `Self employment income` = c(0.03, 0.03, 0.06)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Here is my current code chunk.

```
library(plotly)
Figure16 <- pivot_longer(Figure16, cols=c('Wages and salaries','All Pensions','All Social Security benefits','Self employment income'), names_to='Sources', values_to='Rate')
Figure16$`Rate` <- as.numeric(as.character(Figure16$`Rate`)) * 100

#wrapping labels on chart
Figure16$wrappedy <- sapply(Figure16$Sources,
FUN = function(Sources) {paste(strwrap(Sources, width = 25), collapse = " <br> ")})

Figure_16 <- plot_ly(Figure16[Figure16$Disability =="Disabled",],
                  x = ~wrappedy,
                y = ~Rate,
                type = 'bar',
                color = ~Year,
                colors = c("#8FAADC","#2F5597","#203864"),
                name = ~Year,
                #change colours depending on grouping
                marker = list(color = ifelse(Figure16$Year=="2017/18","#8FAADC",
                                       ifelse(Figure16$Year=="2018/19","#2F5597",
                                        ifelse(Figure16$Year=="2019/20","#203864",
                                               ""))),
                              pattern = list(shape = ifelse(Figure16$Year=="2017/18","x",
                                       ifelse(Figure16$Year=="2018/19","/",
                                         ""))),
                              line = list(color = ifelse(Figure16$Year=="2017/18","#8FAADC",
                                       ifelse(Figure16$Year=="2018/19","#2F5597",
                                        ifelse(Figure16$Year=="2019/20","#203864",
                                               ""))), width = 1.25))
                           )%>%
  #adding line markers for comparison group
     add_trace(Figure16[Figure16$Disability =="Non-disabled",], x = ~wrappedy, y = ~Rate, type = 'scatter',  mode = 'markers', name = 'Non-disabled', marker = list(size = 30, symbol ='line-ew-open', color = "#FFC000",line=list(color = "#FFC000"), width = 33))%>%
  #Making the yaxis start at zero and placing vertical line on chart
  layout(yaxis = list(rangemode='tozero',ticksuffix = "%"))

  #remove modebar as it overlaps with title
config(Figure_16, displayModeBar = FALSE)%>% layout(
  xaxis = list(title = ""),
  yaxis = list(title = "")
) %>%
  #Making the xaxis start at zero
  layout(yaxis = list(rangemode='tozero'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that the Plotly team in Python came up with ([you can read about that here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4913)). Here's a variation of that to get you what you're looking for.

The bar trace code that I've written looks a lot different, but it's doing the exact same thing as in your code.

I've created an object, `cols`, that contains your colors in a named vector. This is so that the second trace does not cause Plotly to infer that changes should occur to the first trace.

The second trace, the one that creates the lines is actually a modified *box plot*. Since there is only one value per group, it's just a line. Since it's a box plot, you can group and gap it like a bar chart.

In `layout`, I've set the `boxmode`, and the gaps between and within groups.

```
                                  # named color vector
cols <- setNames(c("#8FAADC","#2F5597","#203864"), paste0("201", 7:9, "/", 18:20))

                                  # original bar chart 
plot_ly(Figure16[Figure16$Disability =="Disabled",], x = ~wrappedy, y = ~Rate,
        type = 'bar', color = ~Year, name = ~Year, colors = cols, # <<--- color vector
        marker = list(pattern = list(shape = rep(c("x", "/", ""), each = 4)),
                      line = list(width = 1.5))) %>%
                                  # modified box plot for line placement
  add_trace(Figure16[Figure16$Disability =="Non-disabled",], x = ~wrappedy, y = ~Rate,
            color = ~as.factor(Year), name = 'Non-disabled', type = "box", 
            line = list(color = "FFC000"), fillcolor = "white") %>% 
                                  # layout to align bar and box traces
  layout(boxmode = "group", bargroupgap = 0, boxgroupgap = 0, 
         boxgap = .2, bargap = .2, 
         yaxis = list(rangemode='tozero', ticksuffix = "%", title = ""),
         xaxis = list(title = "")) %>% 
  config(displayModeBar = F)
```

[image]